# sql get multiple custom post meta values

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

[image]

What I need is a SQL query to go through all the `meta_values` and look for specific custom meta tags in my case `<date1>`, `<date2>` and `<date3>` and see if they have any value inside the tags and retrieve the `post_id` and create a array to then create links to those pages (see image above).

So lets say the code goes through the SQL DB and like the image bellow has no values between the dates tags it will ignore it and only retrieve the `post_id` 710 and create a array of the ids to then create links.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT post_id FROM `database_table` WHERE `meta_value` REGEXP '<date[1|2|3]>[0-9]+<\/date[1|2|3]>'
```

I think this will do the trick =)
Good luck!